# VS2019: Linking Static Library Functions to DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, linker, static-libraries

I have three projects in my visual studio solution: project A, project, B, and project C. Projects A and B compile to A.lib and B.lib, respectively, and project C compiles to C.dll. I'd like to take the functions in A.lib and B.lib and put them in C.dll - what can I do to make this happen? I have a feeling that I'm using __declspec(dllexport) at the wrong time, or that I'm forgetting to link something.

=== PROJECT A ===

foo.h

```
#include <iostream>
__declspec(dllexport) void foo();
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Foo!\n";
}
```

=== PROJECT B ===

goo.h

```
#include <iostream>
__declspec(dllexport) void goo();
```

goo.cpp

```
#include "goo.h"
void goo()
{
    std::cout << "Goo!\n";
}
```

=== PROJECT C ===

```
// What goes here?
```

Comment: You are going to need to ship (to the consumer of A, B and C) the public headers of A, B and C together with the project C DLL that you have linked with static libraries A and B.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use __declspec(dllexport) in static libraries.

foo.h can be modified as:

```
#include <iostream>
 void foo();
```

Do not forget to add lib file in Dll's properties. For your reference:  [Create and use a static library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-160#UseLibInApp)  and  [Create and use your own Dynamic Link Library (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160#create-a-client-app-that-uses-the-dll)

MyDLL:
Header.h

```
#pragma once
#include"foo.h"
#include"goo.h"

#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API  void Myfun();
```

Cpp file

```
#include"Header.h"
void Myfun()
{   
        foo();
        goo();
}
```

The test project:

```
#include <iostream>
#include"Header.h"//from MyDll
int main()
{
    Myfun(); 
}
```

In test project, I only input Mydll.lib. And I also include directories of foo.h and goo.h.

Output:

```
Foo!
Goo!
```

Comment: @Randy Price Hi, may I know if your problem has been solved? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Not quite. From what I understand, you've basically made a wrapper for foo and goo, which are executed with the dll function MyFun is called.

What I want to accomplish, if possible, is the following: compile foo and goo into A.lib and B.lib, respectively, then "extract" or "move" foo and goo from A.lib and B.lib into C.dll, so that they can be called directly from C.dll. Thanks!

Comment: @Randy  Foo and goo in my  snippet are written in A.lib and B.lib respectively. You need to modify the code in your two libs (remove  __declspec(dllexport)). Myfun is to prove that a.lib and b.lib work well in C.dll , and you can replace Myfun with any function you want.

Comment: Understood - perhaps I've worded my issue incorrectly.

After compiling foo and goo into A.lib and B.lib, respectively, I want to move them to C.dll in such a way that I can call them directly from C.dll after compiling C.dll. For example, using MATLAB's calllib function to call foo directly from C.dll.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to take Richard's advice or make a wrapper.